# Children's activity book, mid 70's, space military manual

Tags: story-identification, activity-book

I am trying to recall the title of a children's activity book from the late 70's. It was themed as a space military training manual, 8.5×11 inches, about 3/8 inch thick. Not directly linked to any major sci-fi franchise that i recall.

The space fighters inside had pyramidal noses, rectangular prism bodies with two tube engines, and the wing extensions were right trapezoids, with the short base joined to the wing over the engines.

The paper stock wasn't  great, i recall. It was available in the US. Binding was softcover, either glue binding or perfect binding.

The conceit was that it was an academy workbook... Many of the activities cloaked real world practical aviation and technical skills in sci-fi, such as identifying fighter direction based upon the orientation of the lights, and symbolic coding & decoding. Plus maps of ships as mazes.

In response to a (now deleted answer) No, it wasn't linked to any major TV IP's. It was not linked to BSG, Star Wars, Star Trek, Space Academy/Jason of Star Command, nor Space 1999.

Comment: This is pretty familiar to me, though I would only know it if it was still around in the early '90s. Do you know if it was available through Scholastic school book fairs?

Comment: I think it may have been available through scholastic, but I'm not certain; I got it as a gift.  I need to add a bit more to the above.

Comment: This sounds awesome, like a version of Space Child's Mother Goose for older kids.

Comment: It was, @Broklynite ... it was. My copy disappeared about 1984...

Comment: Im picturing something mentally, I think I may remember having a copy of this- it would combine very simple connect the dots with fairly complicated math problems and puzzles. Does that sound right? Also, please take a look here and see if any strike a chord: http://dreamsofspace.nfshost.com/spacebookdraft07July-webpage.htm

Comment: '75 would be too early. Tho' the trip down memory lane (many of those are on shelves downstairs) was worth the look.

Comment: Argh this is driving me nuts- I had this but my parents bought it for one of my older siblings so a lot of the puzzles were already solved. I've roped my mother in to see if she remembers by chance.

Comment: It's been driving me nuts. I'd offer a larger bounty if I could.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@aramis I think I have the answer: *Star Games with a Space Adventure.*

See https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/45337/star-games-space-adventure to be sure.

Comment: YES! That's it!